# Draw a barplot by row using R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, row, bar-chart

I have this data frame

```
names    var1    var2    var3    var4   ...   var51
name1   33.87   31.52   18.73   13.71   ...    0.17
name2   36.18   25.07   19.85   16.33   ...    0.21
name3   34.29   22.68   20.37   12.09   ...    0.36
...       ...     ...     ...     ...   ...     ...
name19  46.98   20.42   14.54   15.77   ...    0.18
```

and I need to draw a new barplot by row using R.

I tried this:

```
for (i in df$names)
        barplot(height = df[names == i,],
                beside = TRUE,
                main = i,
                ylim = c(0,100),
                names = colnames(df[,c(2:53)]),
                las = 1,
                col = "lightblue")
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in barplot.default(height = df[names == i,], beside = TRUE, main = p[1, 1], ylim = c(0,  : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

The filter (df[names == i]) seems to be fine but I don't know what am I doing wrong...

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible data by `dput()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, `barplot` wants a `matrix`.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 3))  ## set par
for (i in dat$names) {
  barplot(height = as.matrix(dat[dat$names == i,-1]),
          beside = TRUE,
          main = i,
          ylim = c(0,100),
          # names = colnames(dat[,-1]),
          las = 1,
          col = "lightblue")
}
par(op)  ## reset par
```

### Result

[image]

Without `for` loop you can use `by`:

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 3))  ## set par
by(dat, dat$names, function(x) 
  barplot(as.matrix(x[-1]), beside=TRUE, ylim=c(0, 100), las=1, 
          col="lightblue", main=x[1]
  ))
par(op)  ## reset par
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- read.table(text="names    var1    var2    var3    var4      var51
name1   33.87   31.52   18.73   13.71       0.17
name2   36.18   25.07   19.85   16.33       0.21
name3   34.29   22.68   20.37   12.09       0.36", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Very welcome @Viskovitz It's the number of columns, remember: fiRst Rows, seCond Columns.